# UWP get the vertical offset of Datagrid's ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm using a datagrid from "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls" and I'm trying to get the scrollViewer that is built into it to be able to get the vertical offset and implement certain behavior when scrolled all the way to the bottom or the middle. So far I've tried a number of methods I found in other different threads like the one below, that scans the visual tree and gets the scrollViewer. But the value of the verticalOffset property of the scrollViewer returned from this method is always zero and it's events like ViewChanged  never gets fired, I've tried calling the updateLayout method but it changed nothing.

I've also tried wrapping the datagrid in a scrollviewer and used that instead. While that worked fine, it caused a huge performance issue due to virtualization. So is there any solution to this ?

```
private ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(UIElement element)
        {
            if (element == null) return null;

            ScrollViewer retour = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element) && retour == null; i++)
            {
                if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) is ScrollViewer)
                {
                    retour = (ScrollViewer)(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i));
                }
                else
                {
                    retour = GetScrollViewer(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as UIElement);
                }
            }
            return retour;
        }
```

Comment: Can you get scrollView instance with above code?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes I can, but only when there are items in the datagrid otherwise it returns null, and the instance that I get is useless. It's vertical offset is always 0 no matter what I do and it's events do not trigger like if it's not connected to my datagrid or something.

Comment: There is no ScrollViewer in the DataGrid template: https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml

Comment: @OlegMikhailov Thank you, this has pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Oleg Mikhailov mentioned the [source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml), it was not implemented with `ScrollViewer`, and we have tested with your code, we can't get the scrollviewer instance. for this scenario, you could detect vertical scrollbar's value change event to get vertical offset, please refer the following code.

```
var scrollbar = MyFindDataGridChildOfType<ScrollBar>(MyDataGrid);
scrollbar.ValueChanged += Scroll_ValueChanged;
private void Scroll_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.NewValue);
   // here is vertical value.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what I needed.